# Trying to combine a .forEach and a .map function but I get return undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following `.map` function that creates a new array of elements and changes their selected property to false:

```
const newAlteredData = alteredData.map((element) => {
  return { ...element, selected: false };
});
```

However, now I want to only change the elements that also exist in another array called `changeRows`

I tried the following:

```
const newAlteredData = alteredData.map((element) => {
  changeRows.forEach((changeRow) => {
    if (changeRow.deviceId === element.deviceId) {
      return { ...element, selected: false };
    }
    return element;
  });
});
```

However, this just return an array of undefined. Am I not using .map and/or .forEach correctly here?

Comment: did you tried For loop instead of for each  " for(let i =0; i< changeRow.length;  i += 1){ return { ...element, selected : false }; return element } "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I not using .map and/or .forEach correctly here?

`forEach()` is NOT the right method to use here. It is meant for iterating over an array - not finding elements inside it.

`forEach()` method doesn't not returns anything. Any value returned from its callback function is ignored.

Javascript provides multiple methods to find an element inside an array.
You can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find an element in the `changeRows` array.

```
const newAlteredData = alteredData.map((element) => {
   const exists = changeRows.find(el => el.deviceId === element.deviceId);
 
   if (exists) {
      return { ...element, selected: false };
   }
});
```

Other methods that can be used:

- [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

As @sirius mentioned you forgot to return something from the `forEach`.

I would fix it this way:

```js
const newAlteredData = alteredData.map((element) => {
  const arr = []
  changeRows.forEach((changeRow) => {
    if (changeRow.deviceId === element.deviceId) {
      arr.push({ ...element, selected: false });
    }
    arr.push(element);
  });
  return arr
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can not return any thing inside a `forEach`.

**Change this:**

```
const newAlteredData = alteredData.map((element) => {
  changeRows.forEach((changeRow) => {
    if (changeRow.deviceId === element.deviceId) {
      return { ...element, selected: false };
    }
    return element;
  });
});
```

**TO**

```
const newAlteredData = alteredData.map((element) => {
  changeRows.find(changeRow => changeRow.deviceId === element.deviceId) {
     return { ...element, selected: false };
  }
  return element;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` don't return anything in javascript.

You can use `filter` to achieve what you want and map through only the existing elements.

```js
const newAlteredData = alteredData.filter(
  element => changeRows.find(
      changeRow => changeRow.deviceId === element.deviceId
    )
  ).map((element) => {
  return { ...element, selected: false };
});
```